# How should I make this curly cupcake icing? (Ice Cream)

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, workflow

I've been working on a cupcake, but there is a problem in the icing.This question was closed, but the answer which I was recommended does not answer my question. I have edited it so it can be reopened. The result in the other question doesn't look close to the one in the reference with a lot of curves in it attached below:[image] The orange icing has some really detailed curves. I've tried almost everything, from using a bezier curve modifier on a mesh, or trying to stack layers on top of each other, but without a resemblance of the reference. And also the materials, I tried subsurface scattering but I still don't feel the soft paste look in the materials. Please help, can't I get the same result in 3d? Or is it impossible? I really need help in this. I have tried a lot of things in the past few days. I have not found an answer that gives a result similar to the highly detailed and realistic loook of the icing in the reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was recmmended to edit this question so it would be reopened, and I hope that the details are sufficient enough.

Comment: I appreciate this question, even though I think the linked answer should be recognized somewhere

Comment: Have you tried the *Curve* modifier +*Array* modifier approach with *Displacement* modifier along the Z-axis? Make the curve form a spiral upwards, scale the tip (Alt+S). Duplicate it if needed to fill gaps and make the cream overlap. The texture for the *Displacement* is a *Cloud* with default values. Result => https://i.stack.imgur.com/WelCT.jpg The AO node in the shader is for Eevee to enhance the shadows a little. It's not needed for Cycles. -- Oops, Displacement > Direction should be `Z` not Normal. It's correct for Star, but wrong for Star.001 in the screenshot.

Comment: the video that is linked in the other question may help though: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1xxckEa_FA

Comment: @Blunder Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a *Curve > Curve Spiral > Archemedians* (you need to enable the addon called *Add Curve: Extra Objects*). Also create the profile (like a 4 pointed star or more):

[image]

In the *Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry > Bevel*, click on *Object* and choose the star as *Object*:

[image]

Twist the profile, play with the spiral, you can change its vertices *Radius* or *Tilt* value in the *N* panel. Once you are glad, convert your object to mesh, select some vertices with *Select > Select Random* and move the vertices:

[image]

Material setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was really looking for such a result. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice material, too.

Comment: thanks Robin  ;)  that's the hard part actually

Comment: @moonboots by the way, can you add a picture of the material setup?

Comment: @ Chaudhry Yousuf, sure, done

Comment: @moonboots Thanks!